# C# ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged is like try-catch

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listbox, selectedindexchanged

When there is an exception in `ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged`, the program jumps out of the method, like I would write code in try-catch block.

Here is an example:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = int.Parse("test"); //this should crash the program
}
```

This works fine, in this case it crashes program

```
private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = int.Parse("test");
}
```

This is happening only when I run program in VS. When I run it from Explorer, it crashes every time.

Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe the first method isn't getting invoked? Are you sure you have the event wired?

Comment: Could you give us more code? As for instance: How are you populating your listbox, are you doing anything else because this won't crash at all if I would just run it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have stopping on exceptions enabled? See Debug -> Exceptions for a list of exception and when to call the debugger. You can let the debugger stop either when the exception is thrown or only if it wasn't handled (or both).